# ERROR: main.jsbundle does not exist - React Native 0.60.4

Tags: xcode, react-native, compiler-errors, react-native-ios

I'm trying to publish my first React Native app in App store and when I'll build in Xcode:
*Product > Archive*
appears some error, but i already have main.jsbundle

> main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
>
> - echo 'React Native

Screen Error:

[image: Screen Error]

Answer (score 6):

You can generate a new `main.jsbundle` using this command.

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
```

Run this command in your project directory.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was able to fix the issue by removing main.jsbundle from **Bundle Resources**.

- Open react native project in xcode
- Check if Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains main.jsbundle
- If it contains, remove it and build again

[image]

Comment: Hmm... What worked for me was *adding* main.jsbundle to Bundle Resources. I did this after following @Jay's suggestion and running react-native bundle.

Comment: This felt wrong, so I went back and deleted it. My original problem happened when running Archive, and it still works. FWIW, I installed watchman for another error, so that could be it? Order of operations: 1. Run archive, archive fails, 2. Add main.jsbundle to Bundle Resources, archive succeeds, 3. Feel weird about it and delete main.jsbundle from Bundle Resources, 4. Find totally unrelated error building Android and install watchman, 5. Archive again, archive succeeds. Conclusion: original error was either due to missing watchman installation, or will forever remain a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

1. Clear watchman watches:

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

2. Delete node_modules:

```
rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
```

3. Reset Metro's cache:

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

4. Remove the cache:

```
rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, you should be able to find the `main.jsbundle` inside the Xcode project sidebar.

[image: Xcode with main.jsbundle]

- If it isn't there, then you should drag the `main.jsbundle` into your Xcode project (in the default template app you can find it at `ios/main.jsbundle`)
- If it is in there, but red - then you need to build a copy of the `main.jsbundle` which you can do via `react-native bundle` (and some additional args which you can look up.

Comment: I already have main.jsbundle, but when i run **react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios** doesn't works :/, appears another error: **error index.js: [BABEL] /Users/luislanca/Desktop/name_folder/my_project/index.js: .rootPathSuffix is not a valid Plugin property**

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error because of a bug in the code, instead of using simulator I was using Xcode to install a release build to my device which led to this error.

To fix this, run the app on the simulator make sure it builds and runs properly and then install it on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

1. Go to Xcode
2. Go to targets
3. Select Build phases from the top
4. Just remove main.jsbundle lib from Copy Bundle Resources in build phase
5. re-run again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a path-related issue (React Native v0.61).

To solve this issue on Apple Silicon Mac (M2), under build phase for `Bundle React Native code and images`:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
export NODE_BINARY=node
../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Nict thank you - it helped me! After switching from Intel to m1, the compilation of the application for the Release build failed, namely the error "main.jsbundle does not exist. this must be a bug with". This helped me:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
cd $PROJECT_DIR/..
export NODE_BINARY=node
./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVbDL.png)